# col.gameObject.CompareTag not working! Debug message wont pop up when I collide with a gameobject with the tag "Enemy"

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision, col

My collision detection is not working! Debug message wont pop up when I collide with a game object with the tag "Enemy". Does anyone know what the issue is? Please help

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
//using UnityEngine.TextMeshPro;
using TMPro;
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 3;
    public float jumpPower = 1.5f;

    private Rigidbody2D rigidBody;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            transform.Translate(-.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            transform.Translate(.1f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    }
    **void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    if(col.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy")){
    Debug.Log("CONTACT");**
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of your enemy's inspector?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this already solves your issue but:

The issue might be caused by you moving an Object with a `Rigidbody2D` component by using the `transform` component. This breakes the physics and collisions might not get called.

Rather always go through the `Rigidbody2D` component and use [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) in `FixedUpdate` like

```c#
bool keyA;
bool keyD;

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) keyA = true;
    else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) keyD = true;
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if(keyA)
    {
        keyA = false;
        rigodBody.MovePosition(rigiBody.position - Vector3.right * 0.1f);
    }
    else if(keyD)
    {
        keyD = false;
        rigidBody.MovePosition(rigidBody.position + Vector2.right * 0.1f);
    }
}
```

In general your Rigidbody should be `isKinematic` in order to work

> Note: MovePosition is intended for use with kinematic rigidbodies.